# Loading a remote file into ffmpeg efficiently

Tags: ffmpeg

My use case requires transcoding a remote MOV file that can’t be stored locally. I was hoping to use http protocol to stream the file into ffmpeg. This works, but I’m observing this to be a very expensive operation with (seemingly) redundant network traffic, so am looking for suggestions.

What I see is that ffmpeg starts out with a Range request “0-“ (which brings in the entire file), followed by a number of open-ended requests (no ending offset) at different positions, each of which makes the http server return large chunks of the file again and again, from the starting position to the very end.

For example, http range requests for a short 10MB file look like this:

```
bytes=0-   
bytes=10947419-
bytes=36-
bytes=3153008-
bytes=5876422-
```

Is there another input method that would be more network-efficient for my use case? I control the server where the video file resides, so I’m flexible in what code runs there.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: When you say it brings in the entire file, does it actually? My feeling is that it closes the descriptor after reading a few bytes in some of these cases, and doesn't actually read the whole file. Can you use network debugging tools to see how much data actually transferred over HTTP? I would be surprised if it's much more than the actual filesize.